ServerAuthenticationStateProvider: GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState
I am trying to use the ServerAuthenticationStateProvider in my current project, since we are using Blazor Server. Before we just used the base AuthenticationStateProvider, which also seems to work with Windows Identity. ServerAuthenticationStateProvider does not work properly though.
I register the provider in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();

In my components (*.razor.cs) I use it like this:
[Inject] public ServerAuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;

But this throws an exception when accessing the page with a component:
System.InvalidOperationException: GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()

I am not sure why this error happens. The Microsoft docs are also not clear on how to use this ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, so it might be doing something wrong.

I had also tried using the RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider, but got this error: System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider'.'

In most scenarios, you don't need to directly inject ServerAuthenticationStateProvider. Instead, you can use the AuthenticationStateProvider service, which Blazor will resolve to ServerAuthenticationStateProvider. you could inject like this: [Inject] public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;Register provider: builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();

The error System.InvalidOperationException: GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState occurs because RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider is an abstract base class and cannot be instantiated directly. You need to create a derived class that implements the revalidation logic.
